# Filtered sequence becomes null in next iteration

Tags: c#, sequence

I have IEnumerable object which I filter several times inside for loop as given below:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> searchedTypes;
//searchedTypes then loaded with data
for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
{
    string index = (counter+1).ToString();
    searchedTypes = searchedTypes.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch("String"+index, x.Attribute("Attribute"+index).Value)
        && Regex.IsMatch("String"+index, x.Attribute("AttributeN"+index).Value));
    if (searchedTypes.Count() == 0)
        break;
}
```

At the end of first iteration I get filtered sequence(searchedTypes) but when the next iteration begins the sequence becomes null. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your data source, so I can only assume where the error is. Try the following:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> filter(IEnumerable<XElement> source)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
    {
        string index = (counter + 1).ToString();

        foreach (var n in source.Where(x =>
            {
                var attr1 = x.Attribute("Attribute" + index);
                var attr2 = x.Attribute("AttributeN" + index);

                if (attr1 == null || attr2 == null)
                    return false;

                return Regex.IsMatch("String" + index, attr1.Value)
                    && Regex.IsMatch("String" + index, attr2.Value);
            }))
        {
            yield return n;
        }
    };
}
```

Use:

```
var result = filter(searchedTypes);
```